# Mapping EF fluent API with many-to-many and Table-Per-Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have the following classes:

```
public class Account
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public ICollection<AccountAddress> Addresses {get; set;}
}

public class Address 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Street1 {get; set;}
   ... //Other address properties
}

public class AccountAddress : Address
{
   public int AccountId {get; set;}
   public DateTime BeginDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime PurgeDate {get; set;}
   public bool IsPrimary {get; set;}
}
```

In my fluent api configurations, I have the following:

```
public AccountConfiguration()
{
    ToTable("accounts");
    HasKey(m => m.Id);
    Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("accountid");
    ...
    //This is wrong because it does not allow many to many
    HasMany(m => m.Addresses).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(m => m.AccountId);
}

public AddressConfiguration()
{
   ToTable("addresses");
   HasKey(a => a.Id);
   Property(a => a.Id).HasColumnName("addressid");
   ...
}

public AccountAddressConfiguration()
{
   ToTable("acctaddrs");
   HasKey(m => new {m.Id, m.AccountId});
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to edit the relationship on my AccountConfiguration to be a many-to-many relationship but I'm struggling to figure out how to define it.

The idea behind this is that accounts can have multiple addresses and some accounts can be tied to the same address.

Thanks for your help with this!

**EDIT**
So here is what I need to accomplish.  I have a table (Addresses) that has an Id field and stores all of your typical address information.  There are many other tables that have an AddressId field that points to an address in the Addresses table.  A single address may be re-used by many different relationships.

Now, an account has many addresses but also has additional data about an address.  What I want to accomplish is to have the address data stored in the Addresses table and have the additional data stored in a separate table.  Once again, accounts can share an Address but not the additional address data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't model this as a many-to-many asociation (with a transparent junction table) because the junction table, `AccountAddress` contains more than just the primary key values.

As a true junction table `AccountAddress` should also contain `AddressId`:

```
public class AccountAddress : Address
{
   [ForeignKey("Account"]] // Or fluent mapping
   public int AccountId {get; set;}
   public virtual Account Account {get; set;}

   [ForeignKey("Address"]] // Or fluent mapping
   public int AddressId {get; set;}
   public virtual Address Address {get; set;}

   public DateTime BeginDate {get; set;}
   public DateTime PurgeDate {get; set;}
   public bool IsPrimary {get; set;}
}
```

And your account and address classes should both have an `ICollection<AccountAddress>`.

You map this as `Address 1 - n AccountAddress n - 1 Account`.

To get e.g. addresses of an account do:

```
Accounts.Select(a => a.AccountAddresses
                     // .Where(a => a.IsPrimary // for instance
                      .Select(aa => aa.Address))
```

Comment: Gert, thanks for your input.  Based on my edit above, is there any way of tackling this with EF?  If I were to create a different join table that didn't hold the additional properties, would that make a difference?

Comment: In the junction table you store information about the _association_, not the address. If you really sense that the junction table contains information that should belong to an address then maybe you should introduce address sub types like AccountAddress (although this presently fights with the junction table name).

Comment: The subtype is actually what I was trying to accomplish.  I guess I was basically trying to use the acctaddrs table as a junction table as well as the table to hold the additional properties.  So, the answer then is to make acctaddrs a simple junction table and move the other properties into something like acctaddrextended table?